# Mounting a filesystem for all processes from within a service/webserver

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, python, mount

I'm trying to create a local website that allows me to decrypt a file, mount its contained filesystem and start a systemd service without accessing the console. The started service then uses the files within the mounted filesystem. The webserver currently runs my python code via cgi to serve a simple website to decrypt and mount that filesystem. I made exceptions in the sudoers file for the www-data user to execute certain commands that I call in python.

When I decrypt the file using this website (which calls `cryptsetup luksOpen`) the decrypted device appears as expected:

```
> file /dev/mapper/service-volume
/dev/mapper/service-volume: symbolic link to ../dm-0
```

But when my python code tries to mount this `service-volume` it is only mounted within the apache worker process, unavailable for my shell or other processes (XXX is the PID of the apache worker process):

```
> mountpoint /mnt/service-folder
/mnt/service-folder is not a mountpoint
> cat /proc/XXX/mounts
...
/dev/mapper/service-volume /mnt/service-folder ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

The mount operation executed is `sudo /bin/mount /dev/mapper/service-volume /mnt/service-folder` with pythons subprocess.run().

So my questions are: What is happening there? Is this some namespace/cgroups magic? And how can this folder be mounted for another service/process other than apache itself?

---

**Additional information:**

The `service-folder` exists (without the mounted filesystem):

```
> ls -la /mnt/service-folder
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 23 21:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 23 21:25 ..
```

Comment: Besides it's dangerous to do such things using a webserver, does your directory `/mnt/service-folder` exists?

Comment: Yes it does, see my updated question. Also please note that the webserver successfully mounted the filesystem, but only within the webserver's worker process.

Comment: Usually in a default configuration, a webserver is chrooting to `/var/www`, this means, all other files/directories are not visible for a webserver. Maybe this has an impact for you? Try to mount into `/var/www/yoursite/service-folder`.

Comment: Apache does not chroot. And even if it would chroot there, the (already successful) mounting operation would mount in a subdirectory of `/var/www`. I looked inside these directories and didn't find anything.